# Valores nulos em check box's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orientação-a-objetos, redmine

Em minha aplicação, preciso que caso o Usuário desmarque todos os check box a ele informado , seja salvo um `Array nulo` ou `[].`

Estou utilizando `params[:parametro1][:parametro2_ids] ||= []` após inicializar a minha Action UPDATE, porém se eu tentar desmarcar todos , o rails retorna no log:

NoMethodError `(undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass):.` Em condições normais da lógica , isso deveria ser funcional. Como posso implementar uma função caso não seja marcado nenhum valor ou desmarcado todos?

Meu arquivo de Log pode ajudar:

```
Started GET "/responsabilities/1/nested_knowledges?responsability_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-16 09:05:44 -0300
Processing by ResponsabilitiesController#nested_knowledges as HTML
  Parameters: {"responsability_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mSetting Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'session_lifetime' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mSetting Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'session_timeout' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) AS max_id FROM `settings` [0m
Creating scope :sorted. Overwriting existing method User.sorted.
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`status` = 1 AND `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  [1m[36mResponsability Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `responsabilities`.* FROM `responsabilities` WHERE `responsabilities`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 1[0m
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in #<Module:0x49c03b0> instead. (called from realtime at c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295)
  Rendered plugins/uc_rh/app/views/uc_rh/_form.html.erb (3.0ms)
  [1m[35mKnowledge Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `knowledges`.* FROM `knowledges` ORDER BY nome ASC
  [1m[36mKnowledge Exists (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM `knowledges` INNER JOIN `knowledges_responsabilities` ON `knowledges`.`id` = `knowledges_responsabilities`.`knowledge_id` WHERE `knowledges_responsabilities`.`responsability_id` = 1 AND `knowledges`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mKnowledge Exists (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM `knowledges` INNER JOIN `knowledges_responsabilities` ON `knowledges`.`id` = `knowledges_responsabilities`.`knowledge_id` WHERE `knowledges_responsabilities`.`responsability_id` = 1 AND `knowledges`.`id` = 3 ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mKnowledge Exists (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM `knowledges` INNER JOIN `knowledges_responsabilities` ON `knowledges`.`id` = `knowledges_responsabilities`.`knowledge_id` WHERE `knowledges_responsabilities`.`responsability_id` = 1 AND `knowledges`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered plugins/uc_rh/app/views/responsabilities/nested_knowledges.html.erb within layouts/base (529.0ms)
  [1m[35mSetting Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'app_title' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSetting Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `settings`.* FROM `settings` WHERE `settings`.`name` = 'ui_theme' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUserPreference Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT `user_preferences`.* FROM `user_preferences` WHERE `user_preferences`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (8.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `members`.`id` AS t0_r0, `members`.`user_id` AS t0_r1, `members`.`project_id` AS t0_r2, `members`.`created_on` AS t0_r3, `members`.`mail_notification` AS t0_r4, `projects`.`id` AS t1_r0, `projects`.`name` AS t1_r1, `projects`.`description` AS t1_r2, `projects`.`homepage` AS t1_r3, `projects`.`is_public` AS t1_r4, `projects`.`parent_id` AS t1_r5, `projects`.`created_on` AS t1_r6, `projects`.`updated_on` AS t1_r7, `projects`.`identifier` AS t1_r8, `projects`.`status` AS t1_r9, `projects`.`lft` AS t1_r10, `projects`.`rgt` AS t1_r11, `projects`.`inherit_members` AS t1_r12, `roles`.`id` AS t2_r0, `roles`.`name` AS t2_r1, `roles`.`position` AS t2_r2, `roles`.`assignable` AS t2_r3, `roles`.`builtin` AS t2_r4, `roles`.`permissions` AS t2_r5, `roles`.`issues_visibility` AS t2_r6 FROM `members` LEFT OUTER JOIN `projects` ON `projects`.`id` = `members`.`project_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `member_roles` ON `member_roles`.`member_id` = `members`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `member_roles`.`role_id` WHERE `members`.`user_id` = 1 AND (projects.status<>9) ORDER BY projects.name[0m
Completed 200 OK in 1218ms (Views: 836.0ms | ActiveRecord: 129.0ms)


Started PUT "/responsabilities/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-16 09:05:48 -0300
Processing by ResponsabilitiesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Rp/n7f94mkgQKUkySaGqp+lhcKuMiv8WqPsIIlzkZ24=", "commit"=>"Enviar", "id"=>"1"}
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT MAX(`settings`.`updated_on`) AS max_id FROM `settings` 
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`type` IN ('User', 'AnonymousUser') AND `users`.`status` = 1 AND `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  Current user: admin (id=1)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

**NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  plugins/uc_rh/app/controllers/responsabilities_controller.rb:59:in `update'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'**
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:458:in `_run__296254661__process_action__268418134__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
  rack-openid (1.4.1) lib/rack/openid.rb:99:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__878222876__call__309816011__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: O erro provavalmente acontece porque `params[:parametro1]` é `nil`. Mas com o pouco que você disse, isso é o mais longe que posso ir para ajudar.

Comment: Acho que fica mais fácil se você colocar uma porção maior de código aonde o erro acontece

Comment: @Andrey, atualizei minha pergunta sobre o assunto. Postei o trecho do Log onde clico na aba que chama a Action e quando submeto o envio de nenhum check box , ele retorna o erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido. Coisa bem simples:

No meu formulário, montei o esquema

```
<fieldset class="box">
    <legend>
        <%= l(:lbl_knowledge)%>
    </legend>
    <% for competence in Competence.find(:all) %>
    <%= check_box_tag "responsability[competence_ids][]", competence.id, @responsability.competences.include?(competence)  -%>
    <%= competence.nome %>
    <br/>
    <% end %>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions">
    <%= hidden_field_tag "responsability[competence_ids][]", nil %>
    <%= f.submit l(:send) %>
    <br/>
</div>
<br/>
```

E a linha que eu precisava para fazer o Rails entender que se caso não houvesse valores, colocasse valores nulos é a seguinte:

```
        <%= hidden_field_tag "responsability[competence_ids][]", nil %>
```

Problema resolvido. Obrigado a todos .

@Andrey, @Guilherme Bernal.

Comment: Aceite sua própria resposta como a correta para indicar que ela contém a solução